# What should be regular expression

Tags: regex

How do i write an regex for the following string.  Everything in "ShortCaption" and "Headline" needs to get extracted?

```
  <xs:element name ="ID" type ="xs:int" minOccurs ="1" maxOccurs ="1"/>     
  <xs:element name ="Type" type ="xs:string" minOccurs ="1" maxOccurs ="1"/>
  <xs:element name ="Language" type ="xs:string" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="1"/>
  <xs:element name="LinkText" type ="xs:string" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="1"/>
  <xs:element name="Headline" type ="xs:string" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="1"/>
  <xs:element name="ShortCaption" type ="xs:string" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="1"/>
```

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by everything *in*.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try DOM for extracting in xml! Link to this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 0):

Using regex to parse markup is typically frowned upon.  However, if you use a regex against each line, and can be sure that each line will look like your example above (no wrapping and such), then this will work:

```
my $xml =~ /^.*?name\s*=\s*"(Headline|ShortCaption)"\s*type\s*=\s*"(.*?)"\s*minOccurs\s*=\s*"(.*?)"\s*maxOccurs\s*=\s*"(.*?)".*$/

my $name = $1;
my $type = $2;
my $minOccurs = $3;
my $maxOccurs = $4;
```

I did not test this, but its very basic and should give you an example to build on.  However, I agree with pretty much every other developer in the world...  Using regex for markup is a recipe for disaster.